# problem in showing a modal popup after clicking a link

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm implementing an asp.net core 3.1 project in visual studio 2019. I have implemented `HoursController` and in its view I have a table which has 3 columns and i the last column for each record there is a link called "Details" and if the user clicks on it, he should see a modal that contains the related data. Here is what i have tried to implement it:

```
<table id="myDummyTable" class="table m-table mytable table-striped table-bordered bg-light">

    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>
                Amount
            </th>
            <th>
                Operations
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.HourModel)
        {
            <tr>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ScoreAmount)
                </td>
                <td>

                    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModal" data-id="@item.ID">Details</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

            </div>
            <form method="post">
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div id="result">
                        <table id="classTable" class="table table-bordered">
                            <thead>

                                <tr id="headerrow">
                                    <th>
                                        ID
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        cost
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" id="exitbutton" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Exit</button>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@section scripts{
    <script>
        @{
            if (ViewBag.ModalState == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ModalState = "hide";
            }
        }

       

        $('#exampleModal').modal('@ViewBag.ModalState');

        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget);

            var id = button.data("id");

            console.log("id:"+id);

            var modal = $(this);
            modal.find('.modal-body input[name="id"]').val(id);


            $.get('@Url.Action("Details", "Hours")/' + id, function (data) {



                $.each(data, function (index, value) {


                       var markup = "<tr><td>" + value.ID + "</td><td>" + value.Cost + "</td><td>";

               
                    $("#classTable").append(markup);
               })
            });
        //if I remove this '});' from here, after clicking on Details link, a modal //is being displayed and if I keep '});' here, any modal isn't going to be //displayed. 
      });
   </script>
}
```

Now my problem is if I remove this '});' from the specified line in my code, after clicking on Details link, a modal is being displayed but it doesn't populate its data because it doesn't call Details method in HoursController and if I keep '});' here, any modal isn't going to be displayed and in debugger console I see the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $.get is not a function

I appreciate if anyone can tell me what the problem is and how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this '});', because it could result in incorrect matching. Also, please pay attention to capitalization, although the attributes in the model are uppercase. This is the return value of `$.get`. (I simulated some data in Details)

[image]

Modify this code.

```
 $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var id = button.data("id");
        console.log("id:"+id);
        var modal = $(this);
        modal.find('.modal-body input[name="id"]').val(id);
        var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "Hours")/' + id
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $("#classTable").empty()
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                console.log(value, index)
                   var markup = "<tr><td>" + value.id + "</td><td>" + value.cost + "</td><td>";
                $("#classTable").append(markup);
           })
        });

    });
```

Result

[image]